# Can legacy customer portal users create/update/delete custom object records?

Tags: customer-portal

Is it possible to allow customer portal users (using the legacy portal) to create/update/delete custom object records?

We currently have a custom object for Instances of our service and we have a many-to-many object called Instance - Contact Link, which is visible in our customer portal along with Cases. We'd like our customers to be able to update records on this Instance - Contact Link object.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to include permissions (create / update / delete) for that object for portal user profile.

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work for me. Am I missing something? Have you successfully done this?

Comment: Yes, just adding permissions I was able to do this. There are limits on how many objects you can share on sites. Check for that as well.

Comment: Thanks Abbas, the reason I couldn't do this is because the object I'm trying to give DML rights to is a child object, and thus it's looking to the parent for sharing rules. I've marked your answer as solved.

Comment: @Bradc, thanks. Good catch by the way. Keep coding, keep rocking.